# Syntax highlighting for the processing tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) is a simplification of Java design to help teach programming principles to non-programmers.

Can we apply the Java syntax highlighting to posts tagged with it by default?

Comment: Moderators can do this easily. I've noted your request, but I'm not familiar with this language, so I'm not yet certain that it is correct. I'm waiting for some more experts to weigh in here with their support. We don't want to break syntax highlighting for a large number of existing questions.